Align flex wrapped elements to vertically
I basically have couple of questions with n number of options, these options are under a flex container with flex wrap set to wrap, if the options are getting wrapped i want the wrapped elements to be aligned both vertically and horizontally, is it possible to do this?


.options {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="questions">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>This is question 1</legend>
      <div class="options">
        <label for="1_0">
          <input id="1_0" type="radio" />
          <span>option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_2">
          <input id="1_2" type="radio" />
          <span>option 3</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_4">
          <input id="1_4" type="radio" />
          <span>option 3</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>This is question 2</legend>
      <div class="options">
        <label for="2_0">
          <input id="2_0" type="radio" />
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_1">
          <input id="2_1" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_2">
          <input id="2_2" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>



in this example, is it possible to make second questions 2nd and 4th option to start from same line ?
Thanks in advance.

Don't use flexbox, CSS-Grid can do the job


.options {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="questions">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>This is question 1</legend>
      <div class="options">
        <label for="1_0">
          <input id="1_0" type="radio" />
          <span>option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>This is question 2</legend>
      <div class="options">
        <label for="2_0">
          <input id="2_0" type="radio" />
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_1">
          <input id="2_1" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_2">
          <input id="2_2" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>




I think this makes all the options to break after 2, if i had one more option in question 1 like "option 3" that should still come in same line as there is enough space.

I have edited my answer to show what you are looking for with flex that doesnt result in the different positions between questions

This is not possible without specifying a min-width for the labels and that may cause unwanted wrapping of the text content.

This is the easiest way to get alignment.  Set the fieldsets to be 100% wide and then have each one insdie be 50% wide.  if you want rows of 3 do 33%, 4 25% etc.


.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
label {
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 2px;
}
fieldset { 
  width: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="questions">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>This is question 1</legend>
      <div class="options">
        <label for="1_0">
          <input id="1_0" type="radio" />
          <span>option 1</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
        <label for="1_1">
          <input id="1_1" type="radio" />
          <span>option 2</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>This is question 2</legend>
      <div class="options">
        <label for="2_0">
          <input id="2_0" type="radio" />
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_1">
          <input id="2_1" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_2">
          <input id="2_2" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
        <label for="2_3">
          <input id="2_3" type="radio" />
          <span>consectetur</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>




cannot use width, in this above example, question 1 can have more that 2 options and would still comes in same line as there is enough space.

That is not true, run the code snippet and see

My answer shows them aligned vertically and horizontally

I added some background to show you since you don't seem to understand width and wrapping in display flex
